# Is Review markup required for Google rich snippet if you have AggregateRating?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

Is it necessary to have `Review` markup if you have `AggregateRating` markup?

I would like to have a review snippet show up in the Google search results.

Comment: `AggregateRating` and `Review` aren't related, if you use Review you can specify its `Rating` with `reviewRating`

Comment: @marcanuy I think that if the website is about the Reviewing a Product with a Single Person then Review Markup. When it is a Group Review then AggregateRating Markup.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don’t need `Review` items for getting the [Aggregated Rating Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#aggregated_rating_type_definition).

See their examples:

- [Aggregate rating examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#aggregate_rating_examples)
- [Aggregate rating with no best score](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#aggregate-rating-with-no-best-score)

Except for the `AggregateRating` item, they only contain the item that gets rated (`Book` in their case).